# Fail to purchase an item (already owned) after consuming the item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing an Android application that supports In-App purchase.

I uploaded the signed APK to Play Console as Draft (without publishing to public) and created some items.

I successfully purchased an item and do have consume the item after verifying the receipt.

```
String purchaseToken = (new JSONObject(purchaseData)).getString("purchaseToken");
int result = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken);
```

The consume result is 0.

However, when I purchase the consumable item again, it FAIL with response 7 (Already owned)

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), productId, "inapp", payLoad);
if (buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0){
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
  startIntentSenderForResult(...Skiped);
} else {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Response = " + buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE"));
  // The logcat shows 7(Already owned)
}
```

I cannot purchase the item any more even if I cancel the order in Google Wallet, or change the purchaseToken in Consume() as "inapp:com.packageName:android.test.purchased" (All other token values return error code 5)

Anything wrong in my consume function?
Thank you in advance

> Update
>
> I found that I should always upload the latest APK to play store draft for testing.
>   The **getBuyIntent** now return success and I can **startIntentSenderForResult**
>
> However, the pop up dialog(which created by Android) still showing "Already owned"

.

> Update again.
>
> The issue only exist in my first development device....!!!
>   It works great on other testing devices.

Comment: Is the item marked as _consumable_?

Comment: The item is UNMANAGED PRODUCT (with API v3, it is treated as MANAGED). It there an extra option named consumable?

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).

Comment: I have read that for many times. My question is that.. I have consume the product, but it is still "owned".

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Developer Support recently made some changes, now the app must be published and not in draft mode. Alpha or Beta is fine but in Alpha draft or Beta draft mode can't test the purchases.